# How do i retransform my unstandardized coefficient?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, data-transformation, logarithm

I have preformed one of my first multiple linear regressions in SPSS, and i am unsure how to proceed.

My dependant variable was not normally distributed, so i transformed it with log10(x+1), since it had values of 0. 
My three independant variables was also transformed with log10(x+1) to fulfill the assumptions for multiple linear regression (and they did also contain values of 0).

For the anova p<0.05, and one of the independant variables had a significant impact on my dependant variable p<0.05

The unstandardized coefficiant here is negative, which means that this indipendant variable has a negative impact on my dependant variable, right? 
I know that i have to retransform the actual number i obtained, but i do not know how to. How can i retransform this variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you visually inspect scatterplots of each independent variable vs. the dependent variable, both before and after the transform, just to make sure you have not overlooked anything obvious. This should be fairly quick to perform.

Comment: Multiple linear regression does have any problems when the independent variables have values of zero.  What do you mean by the "actual number I obtained"?  Would that be the coefficient?  And could you explain what a "retransformation" might mean?